# How to determine if a PostgreSQL connection is to Postgres or EnterpriseDB

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, enterprisedb

My current programming project has me accessing a PostgreSQL database in Python3 using psycopg2 library. Although everything is going well, I am finding there are subtle differences between the open-source PostgreSQL and the EnterpriseDB version (also known as Postgres Plus Advanced Server or PPAS). Thus, I need to be able to determine if a database connection is to a PPAS instance or a regular PostgreSQL instance.

**Is there a way to do this via the psycopg2 API or by querying the database?**

I suspect there might be a way to do this using `SELECT version()` but I am unsure what possible values I might see to indicate which platform I am on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PPAS is a *superset* (?) of Postgresql you can issue a query calling a function or system table that only exists in PPAS.

- If it succeeds it's PPAS.
- If it fails then it's not PPAS and should be Postgresql. Or you are unlucky enough to be some other kind of error.

Comment: Yep. Look in `information_schema` for a catalog that's only present in EDB for example.